# difference between values in different rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to subtract values in a particular group from a value from another row within the same group using dplyr.

For example take the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(Letter = c("a","b", "b", "a","b","b"), 
                 value = c("1","2","2","6","7","10"), 
                 year =c("2001", "2001", "2001", "2005", "2005", "2005"))
```

I am trying to make 2001 and 2005 as a separate group and subtract the value of "b" with the value of "a"

Such that I would end up getting

```
  Letter value year dvalue
1      a     1 2001      0
2      b     2 2001      1
3      b     2 2001      1
4      a     6 2005      0
5      b     7 2005      1
6      b    10 2005      4
```

I tried using dplyr and mutate

```
data <- data %>% dplyr::group_by(year) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(dvalue = value[Letter == "a"] - value[Letter == "b"])
```

and it throws in the following error

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Column `dvalue` must be length
>   3 (the group size) or one, not 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After converting the `value` and `year` column to numeric we can use `mutate` to subtract every `value` of `a` from `value` column for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(dvalue = value - value[Letter == "a"])


#  Letter value  year dvalue
#   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      a     1  2001      0
#2      b     2  2001      1
#3      b     2  2001      1
#4      a     6  2005      0
#5      b     7  2005      1
#6      b    10  2005      4
```

NOTE : This is assuming there would always be only one value of `a` per group.

Comment: I tried this, but I ended up with a new problem.
I changed the value to numeric by using the following code

`code` df<-df %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate (value = as.numeric(as.character(value)))

and then executed the following code 

`code` df<-df %>% group_by(year) %>% group_by(Letter) %>% mutate(value = value - value[Letter == "a"])

but I am getting an output dvalue as (0, -4, 1, 0, 6, 4). I am totally unsure what is happening.

Comment: @Molgeek are you using the same dataframe that is shown in the example because for that dataframe I am getting the answer as shown.

Comment: I think there was something wrong with my Rstudio. Restarting Rstudio fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you accept answer using data.table

```
dt <- data.table(Letter = c("a","b", "b", "a","b","b"), 
                  value = c(1,2,2,6,7,10), 
                  year =c("2001", "2001", "2001", "2005", "2005", "2005"))

dt[, dvalue := value - .SD[Letter == "a"]$value,by=list(year)]

   Letter value year dvalue
1:      a     1 2001      0
2:      b     2 2001      1
3:      b     2 2001      1
4:      a     6 2005      0
5:      b     7 2005      1
6:      b    10 2005      4
```